# Differential equations: $f(x)²+kf'(x)+c=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve

$f(x)²+kf'(x)+c=0$?

Is this solvable only by number theory methods, or some basic methods would also work?

All I am able to do with this is

$f'(x)=(-c-f(x)²)/2$

$\int{df(x)}=\int{dx[(-c-f(x)²)/2]}$

Comment: The equation is both separable and autonomous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f' = -\frac 1k\left(f^2+c\right)$ we have

$$
-\frac{df}{f^2+c}=\frac{dx}{k}
$$

then for $c > 0$

$$
-\frac{\arctan(\frac{f}{\sqrt c})}{\sqrt c} = \frac xk + C_0
$$

etc.

NOTE

If $c < 0$ then the solution reads

$$
\frac{\text{arctanh}(\frac{f}{\sqrt -c})}{\sqrt -c} =  \frac xk + C_0
$$

and of course if $c = 0$

$$
f(x) = \frac{k}{x-k C_0}
$$

Comment: This solution requires $c>0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes but if $c < 0$ then the solution is in $\text{arctanh}(\cdot)$

Comment: I will spare you the case $c=0$ ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the insistence.

Comment: I did not insist.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The easiest (at least to me) is to rewrite
$$f^2+\frac k {x'}+c=0$$ which is separable and quite simple.

When you have $x(f)$ just inverse it.

Comment: Here, x' is $dx(f)/df$, right?

Comment: So the next step should be.     $[k/(f²+c)]=x'$.

Comment: For sure ! And at the price of a very simple change of variable, you will face a very well know antiderivative. Cheers :-)

Comment: thanks!!!    Both answers are great. I don't know which to accept as an answer lol

Answer (score 1):

This is also a Riccati equation. Setting $f=\frac{kg'}g$ simplifies the equation to the linear second order equation
$$
k^2g''+cg=0.
$$
Now solve with the usual methods.

Comment: k and c are the same constants I mentioned above, I presume.

Comment: Yes, of course. And you are right to doubt, as the $k$ gets squared with this parametrization.

Comment: Also, what if I have $c'=c+d$ I am assuming I can replace the c with c' and get the same answer

Comment: Is that a differential equation for $c$? If $c'$ and $d$ are also constants, then the substitution does not change anything.